# Fragment keyListener not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to finish my activity from `fragment` `BackPressed`.But the `Key Listener` is not at all get called.I have searched but its about the `EditText` problem most of the time.Below is my code:

```
public class ProductFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_fragment, container,false);


        view.setOnKeyListener( new View.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    getActivity().finish();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
     }
```

Comment: did you try v.requestFocus() ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just override the [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) on the holding Activity. It will give the result you're looking for. Check it out: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29)

Comment: Correct..I know that.But I'm trying to finish my activity from fragment [A]-->[B]-->[C].On backpressed from 'C' fragment finish the activity

Comment: So...Activity has a fragment B and C?..can you explain it better the relation from the Activity and the Fragments?

Comment: You could also do something like:

void onBackPressed() { if (currentFragment instanceof FragmentC) { super.OnBackPressed()} else { //do nothing}   }